# Mixed Property-Based Order 0x V3

Tags: 0x

I’ve managed to deploy my own broker and validator contract on Rinkeby, and the orders execute fine and only allow the target properties to be filled. However, I’ve been trying to mix a brokered asset order with an erc20 order, for example trading an NFT + ERC20 to an NFT with a certain property.

Encoded the brokered asset data and ERC20 asset data as MultiAsset and set it as taker asset data on the order. But it seems to not even be able to simulate execution.

Is this type of order possible using the broker?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, and it sounds like you're using the right approach. If you can share a failed Rinkeby transaction, I can try to help debug.